# std::enable_if_t

Tags: c++

При попытке использования `std::enable_if_t` в параметрах шаблона выдает ошибку

> enable_if_t doesn't name a type

, хотя `type_traits` подключён, стандарт 11. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8):

`std::enable_if_t` это из С++14, в С++11 есть только `std::enable_if<C, T>::type`

Впрочем `enable_if_t` это псевдоним и его можно написать самому:

```
template<bool C, class T = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<C, T>::type;
```

Comment: А как можно заменить эквивалентно?